# Convert name value pairs to struct

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

It's been awhile since I've written this type of ColdFusion code, hence the question.

I am returning values from a .NET webservice into ColdFusion.  The webservice returns an array of strings.  The following code...

```
<cfoutput>
 <cfset xArrayItems=#GetRequestedUserSettings.settingValues.getString()#>
 <cfset xLen=ArrayLen(GetRequestedUserSettings.settingValues.getString())>
 <cfloop index="x" from=1 to="#xLen#">
    #xArrayItems[x]#<br />
 </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

results in the following output ...

```
maxsize=50
isdomainadmin=False
seenwelcome=False
```

I want to put those name/value pairs into a meaningful structure so that I can reference them farther down in the code.  I actually need to pass them in as a cfinvokearguments for the next webservice call.

Could someone please be kind enough to remind me how to do this in CF8?  Most of what I am finding refers to newer versions.

Comment: Hint: Treat them as a "list", delimited by an "=" sign. Then use list functions to extract the first and second elements (ie parameter name and value).

Comment: Inside the existing loop of course.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Got the juices flowing and worked it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up with something quite similar to what @Henry you provided.

```
<cfset UserSettings = structNew()>
    <cfset xArrayItems= GetRequestedUserSettings.settingValues.getString()>
    <cfset xLen=ArrayLen(GetRequestedUserSettings.settingValues.getString())>
    <cfloop index="x" from=1 to="#xLen#">
        <cfset varName = ListGetAt(xArrayItems[x], 1, "=")>
        <cfset varValue = ListGetAt(xArrayItems[x], 2, "=")>
        <cfset "UserSettings.#varname#" = varValue>
    </cfloop>
```

Not sure if an Array or a Struct is a better solution, but the both work in the end.

Comment: Good job. A few tips: a) You can also use associative array notation to set the values, ie `<cfset UserSettings[ varName ] = varValue>` and b) Most list functions ignore empty elements. If the elements can be empty, either validate the `listLen()` is >= 2 OR use `getToken()`, which does not throw an error if the element does not exist.

Comment: I would use CFScript and for-in to do the looping

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately it looks like they are using CF8. IIRC, for-in array loop support was not added until 9.0.1.

Comment: Correct, still using CF8.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more readable version I can come up with that will work with CF8:

```
 <cfset UserSettings = {}>
 <cfset xArrayItems = GetRequestedUserSettings.settingValues.getString()>
 <cfloop array="#xArrayItems#" index="item">
     <cfset varname = ListFirst(item, "=")>
     <cfset varvalue = ListRest(item, "=")>
     <cfset UserSettings[varname] = varvalue>
 </cfloop>
```